# How to check if isset one after another until done

Tags: php, testing, cookies, addition, isset

I would like to test an `isset($_COOKIE['x'])` so that it loops until it founds a free spot.
For example:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['x']) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['x2']) {
        if(isset($_COOKIE['x3']) {
            //etc
        }
    }
} else {
    //do something
}
```

And so on and so forth. How would this be possible to create?

Comment: What did you try yourself? This would take a simple while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Without using a loop and saving yourself the pain you could just add an array to the cookie and add new indexes when needed like this.

```
$_COOKIE['x'] = array(); //Somewhere when you start
//...
$_COOKIE['x'][] = "the value";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x=0;

while($x>=0)
{
$x=$x+1;
$string = "x" . $x;
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$string])
    {
    break;
    }
}
echo $x;
```

Would that work? Kinda simple and will run forever (or until it times out) if the cookie is never found.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'x' . $x`?